# Can a bounded and continuous function on a finite open interval be extended to its closure?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces

Let $f \in C(I; H)$, where $I = (a,b)$ is a finite open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $H$ is a Hilbert space. Also, $f$ is bounded on $I$.

Then, can $ f$ be extended to $\bar{f}$ such that $\bar{f} \in C(\bar{I}; H)$ and $\bar{f} = f$ on $I$?

Comment: No.  Consider $f(x)=\sin{\frac1x}$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @bof I made a mistake. I want to extend $f \in C(I; H)$ to $\bar{f} \in C(\bar{I}; H)$.